# Error in making jar file: "No configuration setting found for key 'akka.remote.artery'"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, apache-flink, executable-jar

I wrote a Flink program to parse streaming data. I can run it without any problem. But when I make a jar file of that, the jar file is not run.
To make jar file, I follow this path:

```
 Flile ---> Project Structure ---> Artifacts ---> jar ---> From modules with dependencies
```

I change the directory for META-INF to **resources**. After that I build the artifact. The jar file is built; even though, I can not run it. When I want to run it, I receive this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Could not create actor system
>       at org.apache.flink.runtime.clusterframework.BootstrapTools.startActorSystem(BootstrapTools.java:276)
>       at org.apache.flink.runtime.clusterframework.BootstrapTools.startActorSystem(BootstrapTools.java:162)
>       at org.apache.flink.runtime.metrics.util.MetricUtils.startMetricsActorSystem(MetricUtils.java:126)
>       at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniCluster.start(MiniCluster.java:260)
>       at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.LocalStreamEnvironment.execute(LocalStreamEnvironment.java:120)
>       at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1510)
>       at PooyaCo.App.main(App.java:38)
>
> Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'akka.remote.artery'

The strange things is that I follow above steps to make jar file for **helloworld** program and the jar file is run without any issues. I think the problem is because of flink dependencies.

Would you please guide me to solve the issue?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, getting this setup correctly is non-trivial. Your best bet is to follow the quickstart guide in the documentation -- https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/dev/projectsetup/java_api_quickstart.html -- which shows how to do this with both maven and gradle.

Comment: Dear @David, thank you for your answer, I'll check that and inform you.

Comment: Dear @David, I followed the link that you said;but still it does not work. I received this error while I wanted to run the jar file: **Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again**. However, I can run program without any problems.Would you please guide me what is wrong?

Comment: No idea. There are so many things that could be wrong. You might want to work your way through the examples and exercises at https://training.ververica.com/, and use that as a starting point.

Comment: sorry to bother you. Would you please tell me my approach is right or not? I ran **curl https://flink.apache.org/q/quickstart.sh | bash -s 1.8.0** in terminal and then imported the quickstart project in Intellij idea. After that, I wrote my code in **StreamingJob** class. Finally, I ran **mvn clean package**. Is that right? Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, that should work. Keep in mind that Flink only supports Java 8.

Comment: Dear @David, sorry to take your time again. I ran one of the Flink example which is **https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.0/quickstart/run_example_quickstart.html**, it was run without any problems;but when I make its Jar File as you said, I received the same error. So, the issue is not because of my Flink program.

Comment: Dear @David Anderson, problem solved. I made the Jar file according to the above link and submitted it to the Flink cluster. It was run without any error. Thank you.